# Circle voice animation in Android

Tags: android

Does anybody know how to build the growing circle animation like the "Talk now" in Android?

[image: Animation]

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with your question, but this is probably fixed to a android theme as I do not get this on any of my devices!

Comment: Thank you @ing0. This is the standard Google Search app in my Samsung Galaxy S3 (4.1.2)

Comment: Ah right, well in that case I'm pretty sure it's part of a theme then! You may be able to reproduce this, but only on devices with that theme. Either that, or you attempt to re-create it yourself.

Comment: @hilbert Did you implemented this animation? I want to implement this animation in one of my project. Please help me out.

Comment: @hilbert : did you implemented this ?

Answer (score 9):

I suggest you take a look at this project.
https://github.com/kyze8439690/AndroidVoiceAnimation