# How to make bouncing circles animation while Speech Recognition is active

Tags: objective-c, animation, voice-recognition

I need to make something similar go what google has in it's Voice Recognition on Android.

I've been looking around but can't find anything similar.
Plus, I'm not a native english speaker, so defining this kind of search might be the problem for me :)

This is the only related question l've found on SO [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124262/circle-voice-animation-in-android)
I need exactly the same thing.

Here is the screenshot of how it's supposed to look:
[image]

So, any idea on how to work this out?
Is there any GitHub solution for this that anyone know of ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ccmradarview 
A customizable radar view with animation

Comment: Hi @JSA986 does it work well without using storyboard ? Currently I've added it to my project but the fade out and fade in effect is not continuously visible as the example given. The fade it only seen at the first instance when shown in the view.